# How to pass a cursor from a MainActivity using SearchView to a ListFragment

Tags: searchview

How could I make my ListFragment display the results in SearchView?
I have a MainActivity that acts as the container of a ListFragment and a SearchView. The scenario is once the user type something on the SearchView and press Enter, the ListFragment will display all the possible records that containing the word.
By the way, I am using a ContentProvider to handle my searching. It returns a Cursor object.
The ListFragment does not displays the desired output.

Please help.